# SQL Server Sorting Int Column bug

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have this SQL statement that sorts the rows depending on their `change_order` and `change_id`.

My statement looks like this:

```
select * 
from change_dtl_from2 
where chnfr_hdrno = 'CH000009' 
order by 
    case 
       when chnorder is null 
          then 1 
          else 0 
    end asc, change_id asc
```

Where `chnfr_hdrno` is the document number, `chnorder` is `change_order`, `change_id` is unique key per row.

If I execute that statement, the result will be like this:

[image]

As you can see, the row with `chnorder` value of 5 is on the top most where the `chnorder` is set its *order by* ascending. I don't know where or what I'm doing wrong.

The default value of `chnorder` is null and is an `int` column. That's why I'm confused because whenever I add a new row, the new one will be on top most. I hope you can all help me. :)

Comment: When sorting ascendingly, 0 comes before 1. It's unclear what you're expecting to see. For all of the rows you show `chnorder` is set, so they'll be all be sorted by 0, followed by the value in `change_id`.

Comment: Your current output is correct and expected.

Comment: Since all values of `chnorder` in your sample data are `NOT NULL`, then the whole dataset gets sorted by `change_id` - and it's **correctly sorted** by `change_id` - so what the problem / the question?

Comment: whats your problem or want to know from the above example? In above example the order by will be as "order by 0 asc, change_id asc".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL does everything correct depending on your query. With your CASE-Statement you "replace" all non-NULL-values to 1 and sort them only by change_id. If you only want to replace NULL by 1 you should use

```
order by (case when chnorder is null then 1 else chnordner end) asc
```

or you should use

```
order by (case when chnorder is null then 1 else 0 end) asc, chnordner  asc, change_id asc
```

Comment: you sir are brilliant! Thanks!